# Edit Text value always equals empty string

Tags: android, if-statement, string-matching

Here's the code snippet

```
 s= e1.getText().toString();
            iv1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            iv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if(s.matches("")){
                        int time=2000;
                        Toast.makeText(Loadscreen.this, "Please specify the level", time).show();
                    }
                    else{
                        int str= Integer.valueOf(s);
                        if(str>0 && str<11){
                            calculate(str);
                            r2=new Random();
                            int nxt = r2.nextInt(2);
                            if(nxt==0){
                                                       //do some work
                            }
                            else{
                                //do some work
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            int time=2000;
                            Toast.makeText(Loadscreen.this, "Enter a valid level", time).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Control never goes to the else block. The output on the screen is the text of the Toast with the comment "Please specify the level".
Please suggest why else part is not executed?

Comment: i think `s= e1.getText().toString();` must be in `onCreate` method? move that line in  `onClick` method

Comment: write your toast like this: `Toast.makeText(Loadscreen.this, "str was: " +str, time).show();` and you will see the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably you are not getting the correct result while getting the text from edit text

write this line in onclick method before any comparison

```
 s= e1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Others can be benefited regardless of if your answer has upvotes. That's not the reason I'm giving you +1.